# upload sound to myinstants.com using java

Tags: java, csrf, okhttp, x-www-form-urlencoded

I am trying to upload a sound to myinstants.com using java and OkHttp.
I used the Chrome dev tools to look at what requests get made and try to recreate them using OkHttp but I'm failing at the login part.

Chrome dev tools tells me that this is the form post, with a content-type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
[image]

And I try to replicate the post using the following code:

```java
RequestBody loginBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("csrfmiddlewaretoken", token) //this token is comes from inside the <input> tag that is retrieved in the HTML of a normal get request to https://myinstants.com/accounts/login and is diffrent every time you load the page
        .add("login", username)
        .add("password", password)
        .add("remember", "on")
        .add("next", "/new/")
        .build();

Request login = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://www.myinstants.com/accounts/login/?next=/new/")
        .addHeader("cookie", CookieHandler.getCookie()) // cookie that is generated from the "set-cookie" response headers of the get request to https://myinstants.com/accounts/login
        .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .post(loginBody)
        .build();

Response response = new OkHttpClient().newCall(login).execute();
```

According to the chrome dev tools, the response of the above post request should have a couple of set-cookie response headers, but they are not present for me.
I don't think the issue is with the cookie I'm using because when comparing to what is found in the chrome dev tools, the cookie matches that exaclty (except for some things that are new every time you visit the site), so I think the issue is with the form post. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Some servers block the requests if they see you're making the requests from outside a browser.

What often works (but not always) is to try tricking the server into thinking you're using a browser. You can do this by setting the "User-Agent" header.

To do so, open the dev tools of your browser (F12), access the "Network" tab and make a request to any site. Then, look into the "Request Headers" section for the "User-Agent" value. Just copy it and send it with your request.

If all this fail, it's possible that the site has a bot protection based in Javascript. In this kind of site, the login page contains a javascript that triggers right before the login process and generates a random token that you need to send along with the credentials in order to login successfully. Since you're accessing without a browser, you can't run JavaScript and thus, you can't generate this token.

If that's the case, the best thing you can do is to use a real browser controlled programmatically. For Java you can use Selenium, but I personally prefer to use Puppeteer from NodeJS. In essence they're the same thing, an API to remote control a modified version of the chromium/chrome browser.

But with Puppeteer you have a little more flexibility than with Java because you don't need to convert between Java and Javsacritp objects and vice-versa.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what may be wrong and I don't have time to test your code now. But as a suggestion, you could try to make the upload using another library and see if it works.

I recommend Apache Fluent API:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/fluent-hc

Comment: I tried it with this and i get the exact same issue, not all the required set-cookie headers. so I think the issue is with the csrf validation